# How do i make this map() application work as intended?

Tags: map

I want to map the value range 0-63 like this:

```
x       y
0-15  = 0
16-31 = 1
32-47 = 2
48-63 = 3
```

However, using map function `y = map(x, 0, 63, 0, 3);` returns:

```
x       y
0-15  = 0
16-31 = 0
32-47 = 1
48-63 = 2
```

Is this due to truncating fractions, or something else?

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: you can use `y = x  / 16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` doesn't *quite* work as you'd expect.  The formula is:

```
(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
```

And all those values are `long`, which is a "long" integer. So all operations are done as integers, and that means that you lose an awful lot of precision in the calculation, since all decimal components are completely ignored.

It means that you only get the maximum output when you put in the maximum input.

As Michael Keijzers notes your expected output is `x/16` (or `x>>4` in bitwise notation), and that can be achieved with `map()` if you set the maximum input to be 48, not 63.

However a simple right shift 4 bits (or divide by 16 if the compiler is clever enough to implement it as a right shift) is a more efficient solution by far, since the processing involved is almost negligible, whereas multiplying and dividing is a relatively expensive set of operations.

Comment: Re “_if the compiler is clever enough to implement it as a right shift_”: it will do so only if the divided is unsigned, or if it can convince itself that it can never be negative.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```cpp
y = map(x, 0, 64, 0, 4);
```

Majenko showed you the formula used by `map()`. You can check that the
formula works nicely if you think in terms of half-open intervals:

[0, 64) → [0, 4)

But this is still way less efficient than a bit shift.